# cast(TRUE as smallint) is OK, but cast('true' as smallint) is ERR

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with only 1 column, which has the boolean type. 
These is OK:

```
insert into bools values('true');
insert into bools values('t');
insert into bools values(TRUE);
```

This is OK:

```
select cast(TRUE as smallint)
```

But these are ERR:

```
select cast('true' as smallint)
select cast('t' as smallint)
```

Why?

Comment: What number is 'true' or 't'?

Comment: you probably wnated `select cast('true' as boolean)::int`

Comment: When I do:  `select cast(TRUE as smallint)` I get an error:  "ERROR: cannot cast type boolean to smallint".  For example:  http://rextester.com/MOAGS72236.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres can guess what you meant when you put 't', 'true',1 to boolean, But It can't foresee what was that you meant when you try to use 't' as smallint. I'm not recommending such approach, but what you probably were looking for was

`select 't'::boolean::int`

or

```
t=# select cast(cast('t' as boolean) as int);
 int4
------
    1
(1 row)
```